# Programmatically open "split" window mode

Tags: office-js, word-addins

Can an OfficeJs Word add-in activate "split" mode? I'm hoping to programmatically achieve the same thing as the "Split" button in the below screenshot.

[image: Split Word Document]

Comment: did you try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.window.splitvertical?view=word-pia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, that functionality is not currently available with the Office JavaScript library. But it is an interesting suggestion. You can suggest it at [Microsoft Q&A Office Add-ins Dev](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/office-addins-dev.html).